# ethereumjs ABI.solidityPack analogue for java

Tags: java, ethereum, solidity

There is a JavaScript utils for ethereum which mimics solidity non-standard packed mode. Is there any library which does the same in java?

Comment: Possibly, but we don't search for libraries here. It's up to you to find them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any concrete lib in mind? I'm googling for few days with no luck

Comment: No idea, but there are libraries for pretty much anything in many languages, I'd be really surprised if there weren't a library that achieves what you want.